# Xamarin Forms: File was not saved on the android storage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, file-handling

private async Task DoDownloadFile(ChatMessageListRefDataModel chatMessage)
{

```
        var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

        if(status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
           await HttpRequestHelper.DownloadFile(chatMessage.FileUrl, chatMessage.FileName);
        }

       
    }
```

public static async Task DownloadFile(string url, string fileName) {

```
        var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName);

        using (var downloadStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await downloadStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

                using(FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                    memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
                    file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    memoryStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

The code produces no error it is just the file was not found on the phone's directory. What could have gone wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you think the file ***should*** be written to?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a new sample to test your code. And meet the same problem as yours. But the problem just appeared on the physical device. When I run it on the andorid emulator, I can find the file by the Android Studio's emulator device file explorer.

The path `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName);` seems be hidden. I can't find it by the device's file manager.

So you can try to use the following code to get the path, such as:

```
var filename1 = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;
var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename1,  "xxx.txt");
using (System.IO.FileStream os = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) 
{
}
```

This file path can be found by the device's file manager. You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this. Also how can I implement this in iOS?

Comment: For the ios, you can still use the `Environment.GetFolderPath`, and I'm trying to find a better solution. @Ken

Comment: I have tested the path just now, even though the file path is invisible with the file manager, but the file is existed. So you can also use `Environment.GetFolderPath` to save the files. If you want to use a path which is visible for the file manager. You need to use the dependency service to call the android api to get the path. And for the ios , you can still use the `Environment.GetFolderPath`. @Ken

Comment: Thank you. I want to use a path that is visible for the file manager and know how to use the dependency service for android.

Comment: You can check the [official document about the dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction), and if there is still any problem. I will do a sample for you. @Ken

Comment: The path still the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249715/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-ken).

Comment: I cannot reply to the chat.

Comment: The file still not found. Temporarily I just use the Launcher.

Comment: Can you find the file on the ios? The `Path.Combine` will not create the file, but the `using (System.IO.FileStream os = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) ` did. I can find the file under `/Android/data/com.company.yourappname/files` folder. @Ken

Comment: And you need to use `var filename1 = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;
var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename1,  "xxx.txt");` to get the path. The path got from the `Environment.GetFolderPath` can't be found in the device by the file manager. @Ken

Comment: Thank you so much for all the replies. For now I am okay with the Launcher.

Comment: So, the path Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath gives me the ability to see the files with the "My Files" app in Android 7.0!  Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Turns Out the `Launcher.OpenAsync(fileUrl)` is just okay to me.